# Swift: Help on Extensions

Tags: ios, swift

```
class quizController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!


    var question : String
    var options : [String]
    var correctAns : Int

    init() {

        question = "What quiz are you taking?"
        options = ["Medical", "Bollywood", "Math", "Trivia"]
        correctAns = 0



    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}


    extension CollectionType where Index == Int{

        func shuffle() -> [Generator.Element] {

            var readyToAskQuestions : [quizController] {

                var questions = Array(question)
                questions.count = questionNum

                questions.shuffleInPlace()
                return questions
            }
            convenience init() {


            }
}
```

In the var questions line, I'm getting an error saying that

> 'question' is an unresolved identifier

I know that the function isn't in the quizController class and that's why, but I need that extension so that I can shuffle my quiz questions.

How should I approach this? Also, I'm gonna load the quiz questions from a json file and that's why there's a convenience init method there, but I'm getting an error stating that

> initializers can only be declared within a type..

so that means it needs to be within a class?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of your code

```
var question = String()
var options = [String]()
var correctAns = Int()
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion plus some other tweaks I made fixed the program!